# Design of opening structuring element

Tags: computer-vision

I want to find an appropriate structuring element so that only the indicated pixels (by X) are removed as a result of an opening operation, while all other image points remain unchanged. I know how to do opening operation but designing the kernel is very confusing. Is there a simple way to this by inspection?

[image]

Comment: Beware that with this color scheme, an opening would add gray pixels, not remove any.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, a structel made of the gray shape minus the two $X$ pixels will do. Erosion yields a single pixel, where the structel covers only gray pixels, and dilation will recreate the structel. [Beware of the confusion with the dual.]

Comment: what is the center of structural element? sorry but it seems this kernel does not work.

Comment: @voldemort: it can be anywhere.